# Running unit tests excluding a specific tag in Catch2

Tags: c++, catch2

Can I run test cases based on "not matching" a particular tag in [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2)?

```
TEST_CASE("Check the data validity","[Working]"){
  REQUIRE(true);
}

TEST_CASE("Check the input","[InProgress]"){
  REQUIRE(true);
}
TEST_CASE("Validate the response","[NotWorking]"){
  REQUIRE(false);
}
```

I want to invoke testcases that are not falling in `[NotWorking]` tag until I finish implementing that functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case add to the command line:

```
~[NotWorking]
```

Source: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/command-line.md#specifying-which-tests-to-run

> ### Specifying which tests to run
>
> ```
> <test-spec> ...
> ```
>
> By providing a test spec, you filter which tests will be run. If you
> call Catch2 without any test spec, then it will run all non-hidden
> test cases. A test case is hidden if it has the `[!benchmark]` tag,
> any tag with a dot at the start, e.g. `[.]` or `[.foo]`.
>
> There are three basic test specs that can then be combined into more
> complex specs:
>
> - Full test name, e.g. `"Test 1"`.
>
> This allows only test cases whose name is "Test 1".
>
> - Wildcarded test name, e.g. `"*Test"`, or `"Test*"`, or `"*Test*"`.
>
> This allows any test case whose name ends with, starts with, or
> contains in the middle the string "Test". Note that the wildcard can
> only be at the start or end.
>
> - Tag name, e.g. `[some-tag]`.
>
> This allows any test case tagged with "[some-tag]". Remember that some
> tags are special, e.g. those that start with "." or with "!".
>
> You can also combine the basic test specs to create more complex test
> specs. You can
>
> - Concatenate specs to apply all of them, e.g.
>   `[some-tag][other-tag]`.
>
> This allows test cases that are tagged with **both** "[some-tag]"
> **and** "[other-tag]". A test case with just "[some-tag]" will not pass the filter, nor will test case with just "[other-tag]".
>
> - Comma-join specs to apply any of them, e.g.
>   `[some-tag],[other-tag]`.
>
> This allows test cases that are tagged with **either** "[some-tag]"
> **or** "[other-tag]". A test case with both will obviously also pass the filter.
>
> Note that commas take precendence over simple concatenation. This
> means that `[a][b],[c]` accepts tests that are tagged with either both
> "[a]" and "[b]", or tests that are tagged with just "[c]".
>
> - Negate the spec by prepending it with `~`, e.g. `~[some-tag]`.
>
> This rejects any test case that is tagged with "[some-tag]". Note that
> rejection takes precedence over other filters.
>
> Note that negations always binds to the following *basic* test spec.
> This means that `~[foo][bar]` negates only the "[foo]" tag and not the
> "[bar]" tag.
>
> Note that when Catch2 is deciding whether to include a test, first it
> checks whether the test matches any negative filters. If it does, the
> test is rejected. After that, the behaviour depends on whether there
> are positive filters as well. If there are no positive filters, all
> remaining non-hidden tests are included. If there are positive
> filters, only tests that match the positive filters are included.
>
> You can also match test names with special characters by escaping them
> with a backslash (`"\"`), e.g. a test named `"Do A, then B"` is
> matched by "Do A, then B" test spec. Backslash also escapes itself.
>
> #### Examples
>
> Given these TEST_CASEs,
>
> ```
> TEST_CASE("Test 1") {}
>
> TEST_CASE("Test 2", "[.foo]") {}  
>
> TEST_CASE("Test 3", "[.bar]") {}
>
> TEST_CASE("Test 4", "[.][foo][bar]") {}
> ```
>
> this is the result of these filters
>
> ```
> ./tests                      # Selects only the first test, others are hidden 
> ./tests "Test 1"             # Selects only the first test, other do not match 
> ./tests ~"Test 1"            # Selects no tests. Test 1 is rejected, other tests are hidden 
> ./tests "Test *"             # Selects all tests. 
> ./tests [bar]                # Selects tests 3 and 4. Other tests are not tagged [bar] 
> ./tests ~[foo]               # Selects test 1, because it is the only non-hidden test without [foo] tag 
> ./tests [foo][bar]           # Selects test 4. 
> ./tests [foo],[bar]          # Selects tests 2, 3, 4.
> ./tests ~[foo][bar]          # Selects test 3. 2 and 4 are rejected due to having [foo] tag 
> ./tests ~"Test 2"[foo]       # Selects test 4, because test 2 is explicitly rejected 
> ./tests [foo][bar],"Test 1"  # Selects tests 1 and 4. 
> ./tests "Test 1*"            # Selects test 1, wildcard can match zero characters
> ```
>
> *Note: Using plain asterisk on a command line can cause issues with shell expansion. Make sure that the asterisk is passed to Catch2 and
> is not interpreted by the shell.*

Comment: Actually, to use tags you need to use square-brackets, ie. `~[NotWorking]`.  Catch2 has the magic [!mayfail](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/test-cases-and-sections.md#special-tags) tag which will not fail when there are failures in that section.

Answer (score 2):

For your usecase of including the test, but expecting some assertions to fail you would be better off with the `[!mayfail]` tag.

See [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/test-cases-and-sections.md#special-tags):

> [!mayfail] - doesn't fail the test if any given assertion fails (but still reports it). This can be useful to flag a work-in-progress, or a known issue that you don't want to immediately fix but still want to track in your tests.